# How to load my page in a popup window?

Tags: webform-civicrm

I want to load my page (Generated by extension which is created by me) in a new popup window. Someone please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use "**crm-popup**" class. you just need to add this class to your a tag. just it!

Just like this:

```
<a href="{crmURL p='path' q="query"}" ... class="crm-hover-button crm-popup action-item">...</a>
```

For more information please follow the Documentation: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/ajax/